# How to pass a form as a parameter to a function using C#

Tags: c#

I need to write a function to prevent myself from writing the same code over and over again.

here is the code that I would like to put it into a function

```
    //make sure there are no other forms of the ame type open
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (form.GetType() == typeof(DepartmentsAdd))
        {
            form.Activate();
            return;
        }
    }


    var newSignIn = new Verify();

    // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    newSignIn.MdiParent = this;
    newSignIn.FormClosed += delegate
    {

        if (UserInfo.Autherized == true)
        {
            UserInfo.Autherized = false;
            var role = new Roles();
            string[] aa = { "add" };

            if (role.hasAccess("department", aa))
            {
                var newMDIChild = new DepartmentsAdd();

                // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
                newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;

                // Display the new form.
                newMDIChild.Show();
                newSignIn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Common.Alert("You do not have a permissions to perform this action!");
            }
        }
    };

    newSignIn.Show();
```

I would have to make the form `DepartmentsAdd` a a variable so I can pa it to the function. also, I have to pass this array `string[] aa = { "add" }` to this function as these are the 2 values the change in my code.

How can this be done is c#?

I have tried this function so far by I get errors when using `myform`

```
    public static void OpenMyForm(string sectionName, string[] keys, Form myform)
    {
        //make sure there are no other forms of the ame type open
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (form.GetType() == typeof(myform))
            {
                form.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }


        var newSignIn = new Verify();

        // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
        newSignIn.MdiParent = this;
        newSignIn.FormClosed += delegate
        {

            if (UserInfo.Autherized == true)
            {
                UserInfo.Autherized = false;
                var role = new Roles();

                if (role.hasAccess(sectionName, keys))
                {
                    var newMDIChild = new myform();

                    // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
                    newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;

                    // Display the new form.
                    newMDIChild.Show();
                    newSignIn.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    Common.Alert("You do not have a permissions to perform this action!");
                }
            }
        };

        newSignIn.Show();
    }
}
```

here are the errors that I get

```
The type or namespace name 'myform' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and

```
Error   4   Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer
```

the keyword "this" should reference the main Parent form (ie. `Main.cs`)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using static method then you have to do like this.

- this will not work in static method also myFrom is form itself so you
- can not create instance that way.

  ```
   if(role.hasAccess(sectionName, keys))
      {
          var newMDIChild = myForm;

          // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
          newMDIChild.MdiParent = <<your mdi form name>>; // instead of this. 

          // Display the new form.
          newMDIChild.Show();
          newSignIn.Close();
      }
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I corrected this issue by not making the method static and also put it in the same class that I want to use. but the issue not is when creating a new instance of the Form. (ie. `var newMDIChild = new myform();`)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
if (form.GetType() == typeof(myform))
```

with this:

```
if (form.GetType() == myform.GetType())
```

I don't think I need to explain what's going on, but let me know if the reason for this change is not clear.

Comment: this is better. The issue now with this line var newMDIChild = new myform();

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to get it to work

```
public void OpenMyForm(string sectionName, string[] keys, Form myform)
        {
            //make sure there are no other forms of the ame type open
            foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (form.GetType() == myform.GetType())
                {
                    form.Activate();
                    return;
                }
            }

            var newSignIn = new Verify();
            newSignIn.MdiParent = this;
            newSignIn.FormClosed += delegate
            {

                if (UserInfo.Autherized == true)
                {
                    UserInfo.Autherized = false;
                    var role = new Roles();

                    if (role.hasAccess(sectionName, keys))
                    {
                        var newMDIChild = myform;

                        // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
                        newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;

                        newMDIChild.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                        // Display the new form.
                        newMDIChild.Show();
                        newSignIn.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Common.Alert("You do not have a permissions to perform this action!");
                    }
                }
            };

            newSignIn.Show();
        }
```

to call this method I call this line

```
OpenMyForm("department", new string[]  { "add" }, new DepartmentsAdd() );
```